# The \n doesn't work in Matlab when i write the datestring in file

Tags: arrays, matlab, file, printf, txt

I have a problem with `\n` when I am trying to write a datestring and number values in txt file

```
pattern = [ ...
     'Date %s - First %d \n', ...
    'Date %s - Second %d \n' ...
    '%d, \n', ...
    '*ENDDO\n\n'];

t = datetime('now');
[fid, msg] = fopen('date_and_values.txt', 'wt');
assert(fid ~= -1, 'Cannot open file %s: %s', 'долбоеб.txt', msg);
formatOut='dd.mm.yy';
dateString = datestr(t);
disp(dateString);
formatNumb = '\t%d';

res = [dateString num2str(1,formatNumb)  num2str(2,formatNumb)];
 for k = 1:17
     fprintf(fid, pattern, res);
%     % Perhaps this is faster:
%     % fwrite(fid, strrep(pattern, '%d', sprintf('%d', k)), 'char');
 end
fclose(fid);
```

I want the data looks like this:

[image: The data i want to look like]

But instead I get data in file look like this:

[image: The data i get]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are only ever passing a single string into the `fprintf` statement, which is only being inserted to the first line of the `pattern` since you're not providing enough inputs to populate all of the placeholders (`%s/%d/%s/%d/%d`). The issue is not the new lines exactly, it's the ambiguous way you expect this to work as written. In your desired output you have different times, but the time never changes in the loop so it's unclear how you expect that to happen.

Comment: i just want to add a string thaat contains a datetime and a numeric value
i cant understand what should i do

Comment: In your loop you are only writing out one date string to the file. That's fine, but it's unclear in your question how you expect to populate all of the placeholders in your `pattern` with only that information.

Comment: `res` is a single string, you should make it into an array of strings, or a cell array. Elements from that array would be picked one at the time to match the placeholders. If there are more elements in the array than placeholders, then the pattern is used again and again until all of the elements in the array have been written out.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: I don't think `fprintf` accepts cell array of char vec, sadly.

Comment: @Argyll I hadn't realized that! Well, at least you can do `fprintf(pattern, res{:})` if `res` is a cell array...

Comment: @CrisLuengo: That'd a good tip! I always find my outputs to have locally determined number of columns. `varargin{:}` would be the format that interfaces my typical data with what `fprintf` expects

Answer (score 1):

Change `pattern` to

```
pattern = ['Date %1$s - First %2$d \n', ...
           'Date %1$s - Second %3$d \n\n'];
```

and use

```
fprintf(fid, pattern, dateString, num2str(1,formatNumb), num2str(2,formatNumb));
```

instead, you will get the desired output.

Note the use of identifiers in the above. (ctrl+F "identifiers" in [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html).) Without identifiers, each time you have a new formatting operator, a new input is expected by `fprintf()`. On top of that, every uniquely identified operator in your pattern should correspond to 1 input in `fprintf()`.

(The pattern in OP also contains some superfluous trailing bits that are not found in the example output.)

Comment: +1. But note that identifiers are not needed, and `fprintf` does not expect a new input for each formatting operator. `fprintf('%f,%f,%f\n',[0,1,2])` works just fine. The elements in the first input are used in turn for each field. If there are more elements left, or more inputs, the formatting string is repeated until all input values are exhausted. For example try `fprintf('%f, %f, %f\n',[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8])`. I find this very unintuitive...

Comment: Oh, I see now that you've used identifiers to avoid repeating the `dateString` input. That's fair!

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if I understand what you are looking for, but, have you tried this?

```
res = [dateString num2str(1,formatNumb)  num2str(2,formatNumb) '\n'];
```